# SQL Multiple queries of WHERE + AND from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of orders that looks roughly like this

```
   ORDER ID | AMOUNT | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
     1         50        JOHN       SMITH
     2         60        PAUL       JOHNSON
     3         20        FRANK      CAMERON
     5         80        JOHN       JOHNSON
```

I have a list of names that I need to pull their orders. For this example lets say "JOHN SMITH" and "PAUL JOHNSON"

I have tried a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE FIRSTNAME IN ("JOHN", "PAUL") AND LASTNAME IN ("SMITH", "JOHNSON")
```

But obviously that didn't work how I wanted as it included. I'm not sure how to go about it but I need to search something like

```
WHERE FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME IN ("JOHN","SMITH";"PAUL","JOHNSON")
```

OR

```
WHERE (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) IN {("JOHN","SMITH")("PAUL","JOHNSON")}
```

Obviously I know little about SQL so I'm getting stuck on syntax and terminology of what to search for?

Comment: Please show us the query result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the logic with an `OR` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE 
(FIRSTNAME = "JOHN" AND LASTNAME = "SMITH")
OR
(FIRSTNAME = "PAUL" AND LASTNAME = "JOHNSON")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) IN ('JOHN SMITH','PAUL JOHNSON')
```